# For loop that writes two arrays with the same index

Tags: javascript

Wondering if it is posssible to do something along the lines of this:

```
var label = new Array();
    label[0] = "label0";
    label[1] = "label1";

var value = new Array();
    value[0] = "value0";
    value[1] = "value1";

for (i=0,i<label.length,i++)
    {
        document.write( label[i] + " = " + value[i] );
    }
```

The label array obviously being for the value array, and they'll always be the same size.  If there is a proper way to do this?

**EDIT: Here's the real deal**

```
var documents = new Array();

documents[0] = navigator.appCodeName;
documents[1] = navigator.appMinorVersion;
documents[2] = navigator.appName;
documents[3] = navigator.appVersion;
documents[4] = navigator.browserLanguage;
documents[5] = navigator.buildID;
documents[6] = navigator.cookieEnabled;
documents[7] = navigator.cpuClass;
documents[8] = navigator.language;
documents[9] = navigator.mimeTypes;
documents[10] = navigator.onLine;
documents[11] = navigator.oscpu;
documents[12] = navigator.platform;
documents[13] = navigator.plugins;
documents[14] = navigator.productSub;
documents[15] = navigator.userLanguage;
documents[16] = navigator.userProfile;
documents[17] = navigator.vendor;
documents[18] = navigator.vendorSub;

var label = new Array();

label[0] = "appCodeName";
label[1] = "appMinorVersion";
label[2] = "appName";
label[3] = "appVersion";
label[4] = "browserLanguage";
label[5] = "buildID";
label[6] = "cookieEnabled";
label[7] = "cpuClass";
label[8] = "language";
label[9] = "mimeTypes";
label[10] = "onLine";
label[11] = "oscpu";
label[12] = "platform";
label[13] = "plugins";
label[14] = "productSub";
label[15] = "userLanguage";
label[16] = "userProfile";
label[17] = "vendor";
label[18] = "vendorSub";

for(var i=0;i<documents.length;i++)
    {
        document.write( label[i] + " = " documents[i] + "<br >" );
    }
```

Error is:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier              print.htm:56

Comment: Proper way to do what?

Comment: What's the purpose of this?  Should the label be an object that has an array of values?  Might make more sense (and be more readable), especially if labels can have more than one value.

Comment: You've got a comma instead of a semicolon in your `for` loop.

Comment: OK, found syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this would work fine. `i` is just a variable containing a number - but make sure that you declare it properly with `var`, or it will be a global! You should also use `[]` (an empty array literal) to make new, empty arrays, and you should avoid `document.write` in practice (but for standalone exercises like this it's fine).

It would also really help if you clarified what you were trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of objects, instead of two arrays of strings. That will ensure that they are always the same length.

```
var labelsAndValues = new Array();
    labelsAndValues[0] = { label: "label0", value: "value0" };
    labelsAndValues[1] = { label: "label1", value: "value1" };

for (i=0,i<labelsAndValues.length,i++)
{
    document.write( labelsAndValues[i].label + " = " + labelsAndValues[i].value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using two arrays? Use an object to hold the key with the value.

```
var obj = {
    "appCodeName" : navigator.appCodeName,
    "appMinorVersion":  navigator.appMinorVersion,
    "appName": navigator.appName
}

for (var x in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        console.log(x,"=","obj[x]);
    }
}
```

And if you are going through the navigator object, you can loop through it.

```
for( var prop in navigator) {
    console.log(prop,"=",(navigator[prop]||"").toString());
}
```